# Make ImageView inside ScrollView twice as big as screen

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create simple map using ImageView inside TwoDScrollView (so I can scroll in both directions at the same time).

Here's mine xml layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <com.example.test.TwoDScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </com.example.test.TwoDScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

TwoDScrollView is taken from here:
https://github.com/derekbrameyer/CustomScrollViews/blob/master/library/src/com/doomonafireball/customscrollviews/widget/TwoDScrollView.java

Then here's java code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_area, container, false);

    scrollView = (TwoDScrollView) root.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

    MainActivity act = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    Drawable map = act.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_map);

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) map).getBitmap();

    int viewWidth = container.getWidth();
    int viewHeight = container.getHeight();

    int imageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int imageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

    int desiredHeight = viewHeight * 2;

    float r = desiredHeight / (float) imageHeight;

    int desiredWidth = (int) (imageWidth * r);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(act);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    scrollView.addView(imageView);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageView.invalidate();

    return root;
}
```

In my case values are:

> viewWidth = 1440
>
> viewHeight = 2308
>
> imageWidth = 2000
>
> imageHeight = 1603
>
> desiredWidth = 5759
>
> desiredHeight = 4616
>
> r = 2.8796008

Yet - it's ignored. Image height is too small (I can see part of background), width is slightly scrollable.

How can I fix this?

Regards

Comment: what is the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top`?

Comment: It's too long so I'm posting it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/1z3VQrAk

Comment: there is no `TwoDScrollView` in the view hierarchy (starting from line #53 in your output)

Answer (score 0):

So, instead of using TwoDScrollView I used just ImageView with gestures support from here (I needed it anyway):

https://github.com/thuytrinh/android-collage-views

And I simply force it to rescale my imageView on startup:

```
listener = new MultiTouchListener();
listener.minimumScale = 2.0f;
listener.maximumScale = 8.0f;
listener.isRotateEnabled = false;
TransformInfo info = new TransformInfo(); //had to extract this class to different file
info.deltaScale = 2.0f;
info.deltaAngle = 0.0f;
info.deltaX = 0.0f;
info.deltaY = 0.0f;
info.pivotX = 0.0f;
info.pivotY = 0.0f;
info.minimumScale = listener.minimumScale;
info.maximumScale = listener.maximumScale;
imageView.setOnTouchListener(listener);
MultiTouchListener.move(imageView, info); //had to make it public
```